# Selecting multiple class names from 'this' object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find a way to get all the class names from an object when I hover on it. Then, after getting the class names, append new css to all elements that contain those class names.

http://jsfiddle.net/fr5q8c4v/

```
$( '.cell' ).hover(
function() {
   $(this).classNames.css( //something like this?
       "border", "solid 1px black"  
   );

}, function() {
    $(this).classNames.css( 
         "border", "solid 1px transparent"   
    )
});
```

In this example, when I hover over a cell with a class name of "one" I want to apply css to all cells with a class name of "one".

Comment: What about elements with more than one className applied to them?

Comment: Use `.attr('class')` to get the class(es), then just parse them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach. You get the class name list, split them and take the last one. Then add/remove a class as you hover

```
var item;
$('.cell').hover(function () {
    item = '.'+$(this).attr('class').split(' ').pop();
    $(item).addClass("bordered");
}, function () {
    $(item).removeClass("bordered")
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fr5q8c4v/1/)**